# ESP32 trouble with running ledcWrite inside of ISR

Tags: esp32, interrupt, timers, isr

ESP32-S2 (Wemos/Lolin S2 mini)
Arduino 2.1.1 on Windows 11

Hello,

Thank you for taking the time to read this post and for any assistance you can provide. I consider myself a newbie when it comes to the more advanced aspects of Arduino, such as hardware functions and 32-bit MCUs. I've spent the last three days working on this code segment from a much larger project, and have searched extensively online to accomplish a seemingly simple task. I hope I'm not wasting anyone's time by asking a question that may have been answered elsewhere in an LMGTFY.

My goal is to output two LED PWM channels using hardware timers to control the frequency and duty cycle of the strobing LEDs. Here are the specific requirements:

1. The LEDs need to be power-controlled (I've been using the `ledc()` function)
2. The LEDs should be able to be strobed at specific intervals within the range of 0 to 1kHz. I'm using hardware timers so blocking functions such as non-DMA SPI updates of the display does not interfere with the strobe.
3. The duty cycle of the strobe needs to be adjustable as a float percentage ranging from 0.01 to 99.99% uptime per cycle.

Unfortunately, I've encountered an issue where I can either (unreliably) time the strobe and duty cycle or (somewhat more reliably) control the PWM power modulation, but not both simultaneously. I've tried various combinations of timer bindings, ledc channels, timing libraries, ISR handling, and rewriting the code from scratch multiple times.

I apologize for the messy state of the code, as it has undergone numerous modifications, and I'm fried at looking at the code. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or pointers you can provide to help resolve this issue.

Thank you once again for your help!

```
#include <esp32-hal-timer.h>

// Pin assignments
#define LED_660    17
#define LED_850    16

// Intensity control variables (percentage)
int pwr_850 = 0;
int pwr_660 = 0;

// Strobe control variables
float led_hz = 1.0;   // Strobe cycles per second
float led_duty = 50.0;    // Duty cycle percentage

// Timing variables
volatile unsigned long on_time;
volatile unsigned long off_time;

hw_timer_t *timer_on = NULL;
hw_timer_t *timer_off = NULL;

bool leds_on = false;  // Flag to track the state of LEDs

void IRAM_ATTR onTimer() {
  ledcWrite(2, 254);
  ledcWrite(3, 254);
  timerAlarmDisable(timer_off);
  timerAlarmWrite(timer_on, on_time, true);
  timerAlarmEnable(timer_on);
}

void IRAM_ATTR offTimer() {
  ledcWrite(2, 0);
  ledcWrite(3, 0);
  timerAlarmDisable(timer_on);
  timerAlarmWrite(timer_off, off_time, true);
  timerAlarmEnable(timer_off);
}

void startLEDs() {
  ledcSetup(2, 4000, 8);  // 4 kHz PWM, 8-bit resolution
  ledcSetup(3, 4000, 8);  // 4 kHz PWM, 8-bit resolution
  ledcAttachPin(LED_660, 2);
  ledcAttachPin(LED_850, 3);
  if (led_hz == 0) {
    ledcWrite(2, (pwr_660 / 100.0) * 255);
    ledcWrite(3, (pwr_850 / 100.0) * 255);
    leds_on = true;
  } 
  else if (!leds_on && led_hz > 0.0) {
    // Calculate on/off times based on strobe parameters
    unsigned long cycle_time = 1000000.0 / led_hz;  // Convert Hz to microseconds
    off_time = ((cycle_time * led_duty) / 100);
    on_time = (cycle_time - off_time);

    // Update timer alarms
    timerAlarmWrite(timer_on, on_time, true);
    timerAlarmWrite(timer_off, off_time, true);

    // Enable timers
    timerAlarmEnable(timer_on);
    timerAlarmEnable(timer_off);  // Enable this at the same time as timerOn
    leds_on = true;
  }
}

void stopLEDs() {
  if (leds_on) {
    ledcWrite(1, 0);
    ledcWrite(0, 0);
    timerAlarmDisable(timer_on);
    timerAlarmDisable(timer_off);
    leds_on = false;
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_660, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_850, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(15, OUTPUT);

  // Create timers
  timer_on = timerBegin(0, 80, true);  // Timer 0, prescaler 80 (1MHz)
  timer_off = timerBegin(1, 80, true);  // Timer 1, prescaler 80 (1MHz)

  // Attach interrupts
  timerAttachInterrupt(timer_on, &onTimer, true);
  timerAttachInterrupt(timer_off, &offTimer, true);
}

void loop() {
  pwr_850 = 30;
  pwr_660 = 30;
  digitalWrite(15, 1);
  led_hz = 1;   // Strobe cycles per second
  led_duty = 50;
  startLEDs();
  delay(5000);
  stopLEDs();

  pwr_850 = 30;
  pwr_660 = 30;
  digitalWrite(15, 0);
  led_hz = 2;   // Strobe cycles per second
  led_duty = 50;
  startLEDs();
  delay(5000);
  stopLEDs();

  pwr_850 = 30;
  pwr_660 = 30;
  digitalWrite(15, 1);
  led_hz = 5;   // Strobe cycles per second
  led_duty = 50;
  startLEDs();
  delay(5000);
  stopLEDs();

  pwr_850 = 30;
  pwr_660 = 30;
  digitalWrite(15, 0);
  led_hz = 10;   // Strobe cycles per second
  led_duty = 50;
  startLEDs();
  delay(5000);
  stopLEDs();
}
```